# How can I get currently-logged-in username from mediawiki/xpressengine?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, mediawiki

I'm coding a chrome extension.

What I want to make is this: check if the user is currently logged in or not. If yes, get his/her username. If not, show login button.

I want to get login status from different services at a same time: mediawiki and xpressengine.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the api to check, if a user is already logged in or not, and if so, get the username. E.g. if you open https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=userinfo in your web browser, you can see the following response from a not logged-in user:

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "userinfo": {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "X.X.X.X",
            "anon": ""
        }
    }
}
```

See the `name` and `anon` keys. The `name` key contains the always the username (in this case the ip of the requesting client), the `anon` key on the other hand is only appended to the `userinfo` object, if the user is anonymous (so you can safely assume, that a user is anonymous, if the key is present, in a newer formatversion of the response, this will be replaced by a boolean value, instead of an empty string as a value).

And the following from a logged in user

```
{
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "query": {
        "userinfo": {
            "id": 000000,
            "name": "XXXXXXXXX"
        }
    }
}
```

See the missing `anon` key and the changed `name` key. Also, the `ìd` key now contains the **real** User ID, instead of a default `0` (which isn't assigned to any existing user).

If you want to login a user with the username and password, you can use [the login api endpoint](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=login).

However, if you want to provide a login possibility for another application (like your extension) you may want to use OAuth, instead of the login/userinfo api, which requires, that the user gives you the username and password of their account, which, maybe, isn't the best idea to earn trust :) Information for the OAuth system used in wikimedia wikis (mediawiki.org, wikipedia.org, ...) can be found at the [OAuth help page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:OAuth), information for developers can be found on the [help page for developers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth/For_Developers) and on [the extension page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OAuth).